# Does Android App-Invite support localization?

Tags: android, google-app-invites

I have setup Android App Invite for my app and translated all the strings.
When I send the app invites, the text in the email is always the first lines of the play store app description in the default app language (EN).

On the play store, the description page is translated in 3 languages : en-US, de-DE and fr-FR.

How can I set up app invite to pick the same langage as the device if it is German or French?

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, no solution found